# Java. Удаление из файла строки по предзаписаному ID. Написание простой БД

Tags: java, база-данных, файлы

Дали мне мучительную лабораторную работу в универе(( 
Задача такова: написать свою базу данных по теме "Баскетбольная команда" с базовыми функциями БД(удалить по айди, вставка новых записей, модификация записей и т.д.).

Сейчас застрял как раз таки на удалении информации по ID. Поэтому прошу помощи. 
Да и вообщем хотел бы несколько советов по всеобщему написанию, логики БД и тому подобное, так как для меня это жуть.

Поясню свою логику к коду наведенном ниже. 
Записываю всё в текстовый документ, создал клас команды и игрока, где прописываю весь функционал. Сначала методом createTeam() создаю некий шаблон в файле, над которым далее планирую работать. При написании метода deleteById() столкнулся с проблемой, что не знаю как удалить именно ту строку которую нужно и переписать в новый файл(для сравнения, до и после), так, чтобы в итоге вся "БД" не записалась в одну длинную строчку.

**Cам код, клас команды Chicago Bulls:**
import java.io.*;

public class ChicagoBulls {

```
static class Player{

    private int Id;
    private int Age;
    private String Name;
    private String Surname;
    private int Height;
    private int Salary;
    private String KPI;
    private String Shoes;
    private  int Goals;

    Player(int id, int age, String name, String surname, int height,
           int salary, String kpi, String shoes, int goals) {
        Goals = goals;
        Id = id;
        Age = age;
        Name = name;
        Surname = surname;
        Height = height;
        Salary = salary;
        KPI = kpi;
        Shoes = shoes;

    }


    public String getShoes() {
        return Shoes;
    }

    public void setShoes(String shoes) {
        Shoes = shoes;
    }


    public int getSalary() {
        return Salary;
    }

    public void setSalary(int salary) {
        Salary = salary;
    }


    public String getKPI() {
        return KPI;
    }

    public void setKPI(String KPI) {
        this.KPI = KPI;
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return Height;
    }

    public void setHeight(int height) {
        Height = height;
    }


    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return Surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        Surname = surname;
    }



    public int getAge() {
        return Age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        Age = age;
    }


    public int getId() {
        return Id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        Id = id;
    }
    public int getGoals() {
        return Goals;
    }

    public void setGoals(int goals) {
        Goals = goals;
    }



}

public void createTeam(int quantity) throws Exception {
    File newFile = new File("NewFile.txt");
    FileWriter newFileReader = new FileWriter(newFile);
    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(newFileReader);

    bufferedWriter.write("|ID|\t"
            + "|     AGE      |\t"
            + "|     NAME     |\t"
            + "|    SURNAME   |\t"
            + "|     HEIGHT   |\t"
            + "|    SALARY    |\t"
            + "|     KPI      |\t"
            + "|    SHOES     |\t"
            + "|    Goals     |\t\n");
    int counter = quantity;
    for (int i = 0; i <= quantity; i++) {


        Player defaultPlayer = new Player(i, 19, "DefName", "DefSurname", 180, 6000, "Good", "Nike", 0);


        if (defaultPlayer.getId()<=9) {
            bufferedWriter.write("|0" + defaultPlayer.getId() + "|\t");
            bufferedWriter.write("|" + defaultPlayer.getAge() + "              |\t");

            bufferedWriter.write("|" + defaultPlayer.getName() + "      |\t");
            bufferedWriter.write("|" + defaultPlayer.getSurname() + "      |\t");
            bufferedWriter.write("|" + defaultPlayer.getHeight() + "                |\t");
            bufferedWriter.write("|" + defaultPlayer.getSalary() + "              |\t");
            bufferedWriter.write( "|" + defaultPlayer.getKPI() + "         |\t");
            bufferedWriter.write( "|" + defaultPlayer.getShoes() + "             |\t");
            bufferedWriter.write( "|" + defaultPlayer.getGoals() + "                |\t");



        }else{
            bufferedWriter.write("|" + defaultPlayer.getId() + "|\t");
            bufferedWriter.write("|" + defaultPlayer.getAge() + "              |\t");

            bufferedWriter.write("|" + defaultPlayer.getName() + "      |\t");
            bufferedWriter.write("|" + defaultPlayer.getSurname() + "      |\t");
            bufferedWriter.write("|" + defaultPlayer.getHeight() + "                |\t");
            bufferedWriter.write("|" + defaultPlayer.getSalary() + "              |\t");
            bufferedWriter.write( "|" + defaultPlayer.getKPI() + "         |\t");
            bufferedWriter.write( "|" + defaultPlayer.getShoes() + "             |\t");
            bufferedWriter.write( "|" + defaultPlayer.getGoals() + "                |\t");


        }

       bufferedWriter.newLine();



    }
    bufferedWriter.close();
    newFileReader.close();

}
public void deleteByID(int id) throws Exception {

    FileReader file = new FileReader("NewFile.txt");
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(file);
    String idLine = bufferedReader.readLine();
    int idIndex = idLine.indexOf(id);
    int nextIdIndex = idLine.indexOf(id + 1);

}
```

}

**Ну и Main**
public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ChicagoBulls team = new ChicagoBulls();
    team.createTeam(30);

}
```

}

Comment: почему не используете какую либо субд?

Comment: Не называется это бд, что намного сложнее.

Answer (score 1):

Есть пара вариантов:

писать/читать фаил построчно. Например, номер строки == id....

ну или можно читать все строчки подряд и искать в каждой из них нужный id чтобы с этим кусочком данных произвести какие-то манипуляции

Можно поступить и по другому. Организовать хранилище данных через List и потом просто сериализовать/десериализовать этот список целиком

Ниже привожу очень упрощенный но действующий код

class Player implements Serializable {

```
private int Id;
private int Age;
private String Name;
private String Surname;
private int Height;
private int Salary;
private String KPI;
private String Shoes;
private int Goals;

Player(int age, String name, String surname, int height,
       int salary, String kpi, String shoes, int goals) {
    Goals = goals; Age = age; Name = name; Surname = surname;
    Height = height; Salary = salary; KPI = kpi; Shoes = shoes;
}

public String getShoes()   { return Shoes;   }
public int    getSalary()  { return Salary;  }
public String getKPI()     { return KPI;     }
public int    getHeight()  { return Height;  }
public String getSurname() { return Surname; }
public String getName()    { return Name;    }
public int    getAge()     { return Age;     }
public int    getId()      { return Id;      }
public int    getGoals()   { return Goals;   }

public void setShoes   (String shoes)   { Shoes = shoes;     }
public void setSalary  (int salary)     { Salary = salary;   }
public void setKPI     (String KPI)     { this.KPI = KPI;    }
public void setHeight  (int height)     { Height = height;   }
public void setName    (String name)    { Name = name;       }
public void setSurname (String surname) { Surname = surname; }
public void setAge     (int age)        { Age = age;         }
public void setId      (int id)         { Id = id;           }
public void setGoals   (int goals)      { Goals = goals;     }
```

}

public class DBofPlayers {

```
private String file = "players.save";
private List<Player> players = new ArrayList<>();

public void add    (Player player) { player.setId( players.size() ); players.add(player); }
public void delete (int id)        { players.removeIf(player -> player.getId()==id); }
public Player get  (int id)        { return players.get(id); }
public int  size   ()              { return players.size(); }

public void save() {
    try (ObjectOutputStream bOS = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream( file ))) {
        bOS.writeObject(players);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Ошибка сохранения данных на жесткий диск: " + e.getMessage() );
    }
}

public void load() {
    try (ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(file))) {
        players = (List<Player>) ois.readObject();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Ошибка чтения данных с жесткого диска: " + e.getMessage() );
    }
}
```

}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Player defaultPlayer = new Player(19, "DefName", "DefSurname", 180, 6000, "Good", "Nike", 0);

```
DBofPlayers db1 = new DBofPlayers();
db1.add( defaultPlayer );
db1.save();

DBofPlayers db2 = new DBofPlayers();
db2.load();

if (db1.size() == db2.size())
    System.out.println("Load data successful");
else
    System.out.println("Load data wrong!");

System.out.println( db1.get(0) );

db2.delete(0);

if (db2.size() == 0)
    System.out.println("Delete by id successful");
else
    System.out.println("Delete by id  wrong!");
}
```

}

Comment: Я за 2 вариант!